# Python Mock function return always False

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I try to add unit test in python in function that save stats in a file

Here is the function for saving

```
def save_file_if_necessary(file_path, content, current_time, mode="w", delta_time=60, force=False):
    if file_path not in file_save or current_time - file_save[file_path] >= delta_time or force:
        with codecs.open(file_path, mode, encoding="utf-8") as written_file:
            written_file.write(content)
            file_save[file_path] = time.time()
            print "yes"
            return True
    else:
        print "not necessary"
        return False
```

I make a call of this function like that

```
def test_function():
    bot_url_dic = {"seven1": 10,
                   "seven2": 20
                  }
    save_file_if_necessary(os.path.join("./", "recipients.bots"),json.dumps(bot_url_dic, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4), time.time())
```

And i made some unittest with mock to test if the function is called

```
from test import save_file_if_necessary, test_function

    def test_call_save_file_if_necessary(self):
        """test function to test add in list."""
        ip_dic = ["seven1", "seven2", "seven3"]
        save_file_if_necessary = Mock()

        test_function()
        self.assertTrue(save_file_if_necessary.called)
```

But the problem is Mock is always return False but the function is called at least one time.

```
self.assertTrue(save_file_if_necessary.called)
AssertionError: False is not true
```

(python version 2.7.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *import the module where the function is defined* and assign a `Mock` to your function:

```
import test

def test_call_save_file_if_necessary(self):
    """test function to test add in list."""
    ip_dic = ["seven1", "seven2", "seven3"]
    test.save_file_if_necessary = Mock()

    test.test_function()
    self.assertTrue(test.save_file_if_necessary.called)
```

Or, use the [patching function](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/blob/master/mock/mock.py#L1595) instead.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day :)
But why this : 
from test import save_file_if_necessary, test_function didn't worked ?

Comment: Be sure to read http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch

Comment: Please don't encourage to patch the reference without any context control: he'll come back later with some other **trivial** question about it.

Answer (score 3):

All you've done is create a new Mock object, coincidentally called "save_file_if_necessary". You haven't done anything to replace the actual function with your mock.

You need to use the [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) functionality to actually do that:

```
@mock.patch('my_test_module.save_file_if_necessary')
def test_call_save_file_if_necessary(self, mock_function):
    ip_dic = ["seven1", "seven2", "seven3"]

    test_function()
    self.assertTrue(mock_file.called)
```